# Notify When Debian Process is Finished-PYTHON

Tags: python, process, notify

I was wondering if there is a way for Python (2.7 or 3) to notify when a process that takes a long time finishes? The process will be executed through the terminal. I haven't got the slightest clue on where to start.

Comment: what kind of process? Is it python code?

Comment: Sorry I should've specified. No it's a bash command that scans the system.

Comment: why not just check the pid?  Or pgrep. pidof etc..

Comment: It honestly didn't occur to me...thanks for your quick help.